# Calling Multiple SQL Tables In The Same View

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I have multiple tables I need to display in a single view. This seems to be a problem because the view only allows for one model definition from what I can tell. I've tried implementing a workaround solution, but have been unsuccessful. 
Specifically, I get the error message: "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[BillingApp.Models.HEADER_RECORD]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[BillingApp.Models.tbl1join]'."

The View

```
@model IEnumerable<BillingApp.Models.tbl1join>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "TABLE 01 DISPLAY";
Layout = "../Shared/Layout2.cshtml";    
}
@section featured2 {
<html>
<body>

~excluding tables because there are too many fields~


</body></html>   
  }
```

class joining two of the tables (tbl1join.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace BillingApp.Models
{
public class tbl1join
{
    public HEADER_RECORD HeaderRecord { get; set; }
    public HEADER_EXTENSION_RECORD ExtensionRecord { get; set; }
}

}
```

The Model Definitions:

HEADER_RECORD.cs

```
namespace BillingApp.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class HEADER_RECORD
{
    public int HRID { get; set; }
    public string TABLE_NUMBER { get; set; }
    public string COMPANY { get; set; }
    public string STATE_CODE { get; set; }
    public string BILL_CODE { get; set; }
    public string RECORD_TYPE { get; set; }
    public string MASK_EXTENSION_ID { get; set; }
    public string OVERPAYMENT_LIMIT { get; set; }
    public string UNDERPAYMENT_LIMIT { get; set; }
    public string REFUND_ACTION_OVR { get; set; }
    public string REFUND_ACTION_PAR { get; set; }
    public string REFUND_ACTION_RTN_PRM { get; set; }
    public string REFUND_ACTION_CNC { get; set; }
    public string EFT_PAC_OPTION { get; set; }
    public string EFT_PAC_NOTICE { get; set; }
    public string EFT_PAC_NSF_LIMIT { get; set; }
    public string PREMIUM_ROUNDING { get; set; }
    public string DB_CC_OPTION { get; set; }
    public string NSF_CHECK_LIMIT { get; set; }
    public string NSF_CHECK_OPTION { get; set; }
    public string FIRST_TERM_BILLING { get; set; }
    public string CARRY_DATE_OPTION { get; set; }
    public string ENDORSEMENT_DAYS { get; set; }
    public string DATE_METHOD { get; set; }
    public string RENEWAL_OPTION { get; set; }
    public string DROP_DAYS { get; set; }
    public string MULTI_PAY_IND { get; set; }
    public string MINIMUM_INSTALLMENT { get; set; }
    public string ENDORSEMENT_ACTION { get; set; }
    public string I_OR_S_OPTION_DAYS { get; set; }
    public string S_OPTION_PERCENT { get; set; }
    public string SERVICE_CHARGE_PREPAID { get; set; }
    public string REINSTATE_OPTION { get; set; }
    public string CASH_WITH_APPLICATION { get; set; }
    public string DB_CC_NOTICE { get; set; }
    public string DOWN_PAY_DAYS { get; set; }
    public string MONTH_BY_TERM { get; set; }
    public string LEAD_MONTHS { get; set; }
    public string INITIAL_MONTHS { get; set; }
    public string DB_CC_REJECTS { get; set; }
    public string RETURN_ENDORSEMENT_OPTION { get; set; }
    public string RETURN_SPLIT_OPTION_PERCENT { get; set; }
    public string AUTOMATED_REFUND_DAYS { get; set; }
    public string RENEWAL_OPTION_BILL_PLAN { get; set; }
    public string EFFECTIVE_DATE { get; set; }
    public string MISC_DATA { get; set; }
    public string MISC_DATA2 { get; set; }
}
}
```

HEADER_EXTENSION_RECORD.cs

```
namespace BillingApp.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class HEADER_EXTENSION_RECORD
{
    public int ERID { get; set; }
    public string ETABLE_NUMBER { get; set; }
    public string ECOMPANY { get; set; }
    public string ESTATE_CODE { get; set; }
    public string EBILL_CODE { get; set; }
    public string ERECORD_TYPE { get; set; }
    public string EMASK_EXTENSION_ID { get; set; }
    public string OVERPAYMENT_TOLERANCE_PERCENT { get; set; }
    public string UNDERPAYMENT_TOLERANCE_PERCENT { get; set; }
}
}
```

The Controller (BillingController.cs)

```
  public ActionResult HeaderExtensionRecord()
    {
        {
            return View(db.HEADER_EXTENSION_RECORD);
        }
    }


 public ActionResult HeaderRecordTable1()
    {
        {
            return View(db.HEADER_RECORD);
        }
    }
```

**Update:**

Added tbl1join as the return type in the controller, but gives an error saying it's a type being used as a variable.

```
  public ActionResult HeaderRecordTable1()
    {
        {
            return View(IEnumerable<tbl1join>);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you have your view accepting a `IEnumerable<tbl1join>`.  It looks like you have it all set up, why don't you have a controller action returning `IEnumerable<tbl1join>`?

Comment: Is there a relationship between these 2 models? Could you not use a navigation property/relationship to JOIN the data together?

Comment: You need to populate your model somehow, i.e. create `tbl1join`s based off of your database and however you need to join them

Comment: At this point having code to at least get me in the right direction would be best, I've had this issue for a while without having found a solution.

Comment: You could investigate [ViewModels](http://www.rachelappel.com/use-viewmodels-to-manage-data-amp-organize-code-in-asp.net-mvc-applications). Basically `tbl1join` is a ViewModel already. Using a ViewModel you can join two (or more) models to be displayed in one View.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it into a ViewModel

```
public class RecordVM
{
    public HEADER_RECORD header { get; set; }
    public HEADER_EXTENSION_RECORD ext { get; set; }
}

return View(new RecordVM { header = db.HEADER_RECORD, ext = db.HEADER_EXTENSION_RECORD });
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that you are passing in the wrong type, you need to query the database and create the suitable model that your view is expecting. It looks like you are trying to pass 2 models to the view using the view model tbl1join.

You could populate the view model as follows for a specified id value:

```
public ActionResult ViewModelExtension(int id)
{
    var viewModel = new tbl1join();

    viewModel.HEADER_RECORD = db.HEADER_RECORD.Where(h => h.id == id).SingleOrDefault;
    viewModel.HEADER_EXTENSION_RECORD = db.HEADER_EXTENSION_RECORD.Where(h => h.id == id).SingleOrDefault;

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

I would be surprised if there isn't some relationship between the 2 models. If this was specified within your 2 models then the above could be done differently.